# JSON string unable to be converted into JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

Here i 'm trying to build an array from json string that i fetch from a JSON file.My problem is in when converting the string to array.It's not converting.I looked up my JSON file cros-checked it but it seems to be right.But i'm a beginner so doesn't know if there is something i 'm missing.Because of this my application is crashing.
My JSON File is:

```
var Details=          [
            {
                    "Name" : "backtrack" ,
                    "Place" : "CS Software Lab",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Main College Building"
            }

            {
                    "Name" : "mechanist" ,
                    "Place" : "Mechanical Workshop",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Workshop Building"
            }
      ];
```

And my JSON parser code is this:

```
 public class JSONParser {

static InputStream iStream = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        //Log.d("Midhun", statusLine.toString());
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                Log.d("Midhun",builder.toString());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
        Log.d("Midhun",jarray.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jarray;

}


}
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

1.I have print my `line` variable in console.The result is ok.

2.I have print my `builder` variable in console.It gave me a strange output:

I have attached here that in 3 pics :

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am i doing wrong here.Please help me.

My logcat:

```
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value var of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41873e48)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.defcomdevs.invento16, PID: 2126
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.defcomdevs.invento16.Assistence$GetDetails.doInBackground(Assistence.java:72)
   01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.defcomdevs.invento16.Assistence$GetDetails.doInBackground(Assistence.java:62)
    01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  01-29 11:38:51.177 2126-3446/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: why are you not using line variable in jsonArray??

Comment: this is whole json response

Comment: I have tried using line variable too.Same output.

Comment: post your logcat exception

Comment: It seems, that your JSON-array do not have separators (commans) between JSON-objects

Comment: You can use online tools like JSONLint http://jsonlint.com/ to test your JSON to make sure it's valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two syntax mistakes in your JSON**

1. **","** should be used to separate JSON objects
2. **";"** you don't have to use semi colon at the end to mark the end of a JSON file

***The valid JSON is***

```
[{
        "Name": "backtrack",
        "Place": "CS Software Lab",
        "Floor": "1st Floor",
        "Building": "Main College Building"
    },

    {
        "Name": "mechanist",
        "Place": "Mechanical Workshop",
        "Floor": "1st Floor",
        "Building": "Workshop Building"
    }
]
```

I recommend you to use [**jsonlint.com**](http://jsonlint.com) to verify the syntax of your JSON file.

Comment: Add to that the `var` was also not needed.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `JsonArray` is wrong

**you missed ,**

try this

```
  [
            {
                    "Name" : "backtrack" ,
                    "Place" : "CS Software Lab",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Main College Building"
            }
             ,// missed , between two object
            {
                    "Name" : "mechanist" ,
                    "Place" : "Mechanical Workshop",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Workshop Building"
            }
      ]
```

[Online JSON validator/Editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid

```
[
            {
                    "Name" : "backtrack" ,
                    "Place" : "CS Software Lab",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Main College Building"
            }
,// not present in your code
            {`enter code here`
                    "Name" : "mechanist" ,
                    "Place" : "Mechanical Workshop",
                    "Floor" : "1st Floor",
                    "Building" : "Workshop Building"
            }
      ]
```